# Double List Comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I've been playing around with list comprehensions recently, but I've gotten to a point where I'm confused. Currently I have this:

```
k = range(2,11)
N = [2**k[u] for u in range(9)]
i = [range(N[v] + 1) for v in range(9)]

xCoord = [0.5*math.cos((2*(math.pi)*i[n][j])/N[n]) for n in range(9) for j in range(len(i[n])]
```

This gives me a regular list rather than a nested list, which is what I would like. I would like a nested list, with a list for each value of N.

Just to clarify, say if my N = 4, I want to generate a list containing the x-coordinates of the points corresponding to i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. For N = 8, i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. etc.

What I am trying to do is make a list of N + 1 points along a circle with radius 1/2, which I can then use to calculate the path length of a polygon approximating the circle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a nested list, write

`xCoord = [[0.5*math.cos((2*(math.pi)*i[n][j])/N[n]) for j in range(len(i[n])] for n in range(9)]`

Notice the added `[]`. I also reversed the order, since the range for `j` depends on `n`: in the inner comprehension, `n` is a constant (set by the outer comprehension).

If you only want to approximate the value of circle's circumference, there are more efficient ways: first, you don't have to store all lists, only the "current" one, to compute the length. And you don't even need a list, since there is a formula to get the length: for `n` points and radius `R`, the circumference of the regular polygon inscribed in the circle is simply (in Python syntax): `2*n*R*math.sin(math.pi/n)`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand a lot better now. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to combat the problem, but it's for a homework problem with a particular emphasis on lists. (and I'm also fairly new to Python!)

Comment: ... and the formula is ... `def perimeter_of_polygon(r,n): return n*r*math.sqrt(2-2*math.cos(2*math.pi/n))`

Comment: @gboffi It's the same, but longer. Notice 1-cos(t)=2sin(t/2)^2